# Should "seem" be used instead of "seems" in this sentence: "Technology may have made the world seems smaller."

Tags: grammar, verbs, modal-verbs

An editing textbook suggested that "seem" should be used instead of "seems" in this sentence:

> Technology may have made the world seems smaller.

The shorter sentence "the world seems smaller" is definitely correct.

Why should we use "seem" for the longer sentence?

Comment: "Seem" is correct. The subordinate non-finite clause "seem smaller" is catenative complement of "made". "The world" is the syntactic object of "made" and the understood (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause.

Answer (score 1):

When it means to cause or force someone to do something, *make* is followed by a ***bare infintive***:

> make someone/something do something
>
> - You can't ***make him go*** if he doesn't want to. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make))

You cannot say **make him goes*, nor **make it seems*. Your text book is right in saying that the correct way is

> Technology may have made the world ***seem*** smaller.